# Best way to define and initialize matrix in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado

I'm trying to make a program that uses matrices( 2d arrays) of integers in vhdl and i have never done that before.

First of all, is it possible to define a 2d array in the entity's signal definitions?What I mean is something like this;

```
entity Matrix is 
Port ( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
       RESET : in STD_LOGIc;
       Output : out array (integer range <> , integer range <> ) of integer);
end Matrix;
```

Also. What is the best way to actually initialize a matrix ? I thought of doing something like this;

```
type 2d_array is array(2 downto 0, 2 downto 0) of integer;

constant A2d : 2d_array :=((1,2,3),
                            (1,2,3),
                            (1,2,3));
```

Still, I'm not really sure if that is correct.

Last but not least, what would happen if i tried to rashape one of the output matrices into an 1-D array? Whould that solve my first problem, or would that create a new one ?

Comment: If the array contents are algorithmic, a neat way is to write a function returning an array of the correct type, and initialise the actual array with a function call. In synthesis, the function will be called to fill in the array (lookup table) but will not itself be converted into hardware (so won't cost gates) as long as it's only used for initialisation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VHDL, all types must be declared before use. So you cannot simply declare an object as an "array" because you have not declared the type yet. To use a type in an entity port definition, you would usually need to declare the type in a package, and include the package in the entity.

```vhdl
package my_types_pkg is
  type my_array_t is array(integer range <>, integer range <>) of integer;
end package;

use work.my_types_pkg;

entity Matrix is 
Port ( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
       RESET : in STD_LOGIc;
       output : out my_array_t -- note this is not yet constrained - the object mapped to this port will constrain the port
     );
```

Initialisation : You did the correct thing for a 2d array.

"Reshaping" : VHDL is a strongly typed language. So arrays are not necessarily directly convertible. A 2D array of integers is not the same type as a 1D array of integers, and hence a type conversion function will be required.

Comment: Thank's for the advise :) . Another thing that i would like to ask is,do i use the matrices like this : a(row+i)(col+j) * b(i)(j) , or is there another notation ?

Comment: in VHDL, the dimension separator is a comma `,` . So for your array, the index would `a(row+i, col+j) * b(i,j)` , assuming `a` and `b` use a type similar to `my_array_t` from the answer. But most poeple dont use N-d arrays, usually people stick with 1d array types, and usually declare arrays of arrays, as these can be sliced, whereas N-d arrays cannot. eg (VHDL 2008). `type my_array_t is array(integer range <>) of integer_vector` .